# Nand2Tetris Code Module

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm working through the Assembler assignment in the [Nand2Tetris](http://nand2tetris.org) course (chapter 6). The suggested implementation contains 4 modules: Main, Parser, Code, SyntaxTree. Today I wanted to get some feedback on my implementation of the Code module.

The book specifies a general API in order to allow students to use whichever programming language they want; I choose Python 2.7. The Code module takes a line of a simplified dialect of Assembly code called Hack and produces binary.

The Code module only deals with a single class of instruction in Hack language: The C-Instruction. This instruction takes the form `dest=comp;jump`, where either `dest=` OR `;jump` may be optionally omitted. `comp` is one of 28 valid expressions. `dest` is the destination to store the result of the computation: it can be any permutation of the three registers available (`A`, `D`, `M`). `jump` is a condition which, if true, moves control flow the address in *instruction memory* currently stored in register `A`.

The resulting opcode takes the form: `111a cccc ccdd djjj`, where `a` and `cccc cc` correspond to the `comp`, `ddd` corresponds to the `dest`, and `jjj` corresponds to the `jump`. For more details, see Chapters 4 and 6 of the textbook.

Please review on style, implementation (especially those terribly ugly lookup tables), etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# hack code translator

# Sample conversion:
# HACK Instruction: M = 1
# 111
# a = 0
# cccccc = 1111 11
# ddd = 001
# jjj = 000
# BINARY Opcode:    1110 1111 1100 1000

jumpTable = { 'null': '000',
              'JGT' : '001',
              'JEQ' : '010',
              'JEQ' : '010',
              'JGE' : '011',
              'JLT' : '100',
              'JNE' : '101',
              'JLE' : '110',
              'JMP' : '111'  }

compTable = { '0'   : '101010',
              '1'   : '111111',
              '-1'  : '111010',
              'D'   : '001100',
              'A'   : '110000',
              '!D'  : '001101',
              '!A'  : '110001',
              '-D'  : '001111',
              '-A'  : '110011',
              'D+1' : '011111',
              'A+1' : '110111',
              'D-1' : '001110',
              'A-1' : '110010',
              'D+A' : '000010',
              'D-A' : '010011',
              'A-D' : '000111',
              'D&A' : '000000',
              'D|A' : '010101' }


def dest(srcStr):
    # Of the three portions of the opcodes,
    # this is the only one that makes obvious logical sense
    # No point in a lookup table

    # Any combination of A, D, M
    # in that order
    # TODO: bitops this
    bits = ['0', '0', '0']  # 0 by default
    if 'A' in srcStr:
        bits[0] = '1'
    if 'D' in srcStr:
        bits[1] = '1'
    if 'M' in srcStr:
        bits[2] = '1'

    return ''.join(bits)


def comp(srcStr):
    aBit = '0'

    if 'M' in srcStr:
        if 'A' in srcStr:
            raise SyntaxError
        else:
            aBit = '1'
            nStr = srcStr.replace('M', 'A')  # this way we use only one lookup table

    else:
        nStr = srcStr[:]  # non-destructive copy

    return aBit + compTable[nStr]   


def jump(srcStr):
    return jumpTable[srcStr]
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The values in your lookup tables are *strings* of binary digits, for example `'111010'`. It would be closer to the way that real assemblers work if you represented these as *numbers* in binary, for example `0b111010`. I presume you use string concatenation to assemble the instructions at present:

   ```
   instruction = '111' + comp + dest + jump
   ```

   With numeric values for the instruction fields, you'll need to use bitwise operations instead:

   ```
   instruction = 0b111 << 13 | comp << 6 | dest << 3 | jump
   ```
2. There's no error handling. It's likely that assembly programs will contain mistakes, for example:

   ```
   M=-1;JGR   // oops: typo for JGT
   ```

   The user would like to get an error message, preferably one that gives the file and line number and an explanation of what went wrong:

   ```
   prog.asm(17): bad jump field "JGR"
   ```

   But as far I can see from the code you posted, what will happen here is that Python will raise a `KeyError` in `jump`, which is much less useful.

   (Possibly there's error handling in the rest of the code that you didn't show us, but I can only comment on what I see here.)
3. It's even worse for the *dest* field: this doesn't seem to produce any errors at all, so if I write:

   ```
   BAD=1;JEQ     // Oops: typo for MAD
   ```

   then the assembler goes ahead as if I had written

   ```
   AD=1;JEQ
   ```

   and I never get told about my mistake.
4. The logic for lookup of the *comp* field is needlessly complex. It would be simplest just to make a 7-bit lookup table (including the *a* bit). Trying to modify the instruction wastes time, and it makes it harder to produce good error messages (outputting the modified instruction will confuse the user, so you have to hang on to the unmodified instruction for use in error messages).

   If you don't want to write out the whole 7-bit lookup table, then write code to generate it:

   ```
   fullCompTable = compTable.copy()
   for k, v in compTable.items():
       if 'A' in k:
           fullCompTable[k.replace('A', 'M')] = 1 << 6 | v
   ```

   and run this once, when the assembler starts up.
5. The comment for `dest` says "No point in a lookup table" but that's not true. A lookup table will be faster than the computation in `dest`. And it only needs 15 entries. Again, if you don't want to write it out by hand, you could compute it:

   ```
   from itertools import permutations

   destTable = {
       ''.join('MDA'[i] for i in p): sum(1<<i for i in p)
       for n in range(1, 4)
       for p in permutations(range(3), n)
   }
   ```

   but this is longer than writing it out in full:

   ```
   destTable = {
       'A': 4, 'AD': 6, 'ADM': 7, 'AM': 5, 'AMD': 7, 'D': 2, 'DA': 6, 'DAM': 7,
       'DM': 3, 'DMA': 7, 'M': 1, 'MA': 5, 'MAD': 7, 'MD': 3, 'MDA': 7
   }
   ```
6. There's no need to take a copy here:

   ```
   nStr = srcStr[:]  # non-destructive copy
   ```

   Just write:

   ```
   nStr = srcStr
   ```

Comment: Maybe generating the jump table (dictionary) on the fly is better, typing it all out a typo may easily slip in. On the other hand it is easier to write it by hand... which of the two do you suggest?

Comment: @Caridorc: I don't see any way to compute `jumpTable`, so it has to be written out.

Comment: sorry I meant the `destTable`

Comment: @Caridorc: You could do both: that is, compute it and copy the result into the source code. (That's what I did.)

Comment: Nice solution, so that after the computation you can inspect it and check if it is all right :)

Comment: The main reason I am using strings is that I need to write out the result to a file at the end, right, and then I'd have to str() the binary num and then slice off the `0b` at the beginning.

Comment: @Zaxvo: If you need to convert numbers to strings in binary, use the `b` format specifier: `'{:08b}'.format(61)` → `'00111101'`. But are you sure that's right? Normally machine code consists of raw data, not binary digits, in which case you could use `struct.pack` to output it.

Comment: I have to take a string and output the 16-digit opcode. I could do it all in binary and then do a string format, but I elected to just do it all as a string.

Comment: @Zaxvo: Even if you're right that you have to output the opcode as a string of binary digits, it's still a good idea to work with numbers internally and convert to strings at the last minute. Operations on numbers are usually faster than operations on strings, and you have a wider variety of operations available. For example to negate the sense of a jump (turning JGT into JLE and vice versa), you can write `~op & 7` if `op` is a number, but you have to write something like `''.join('0' if bit == '1' else '1' for bit in op)` if `op` is a string.